# How to implement data table in techtalk.specflow in gherkin

Tags: c#, datatable, specflow, gherkin

I need to implement Data table in gherkin. But they allow only table instead of Data Table. How can i implement Data table in Gherkin ?

I have tried:
This is my gherkin syntax

```
Scenario: Select Even Numbers From The list

Given Num List
| num |
| 1   | 
| 2   | 
| 3   |
| 4   |
| 5   |
| 6   |
| 7   |
| 8   |
| 9   |
| 10  |

Then the result should even numbers only on the screen.
```

This is the code  after Generating step definition. Here the function parameter is Table.(How to possible Data table instead of table?).

```
public void GivenNumList(Table table)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Table type is the type which represents the table in Gherkin.
If you directly want a DataTable as parameter of the function, you can use Step Argument Transformations (http://specflow.org/documentation/Step-Argument-Conversions/).

In your case it has to look something like this:

```
[Binding]
public class Transforms
{
    [StepArgumentTransformation]
    public DataTable TransformToDataTable(Table booksTable)
    {
        //your code to put the data from the Table to the DataTable
    }
}
```

Filling the DataTable with the data from the table is still needed to be done by you.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this as an extension method to the TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table class and utilize a little class reflection in C# to make things easy to use:

```
namespace YourTestProject
{
    public static class SpecFlowTableExtensions
    {
        public static DataTable ToDataTable(this Table table, params Type[] columnTypes)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            TableRow headerRow = table.Rows[0];
            int headerCellCount = headerRow.Count();

            for (int i = 0; i < headerCellCount; i++)
            {
                string columnName = headerRow[i];
                Type columnType = columnTypes[i];

                dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName, columnType);
            }

            foreach (var row in table.Rows.Skip(1))
            {
                var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                for (int i = 0; i < headerCellCount; i++)
                {
                    string columnName = headerRow[i];
                    Type columnType = columnTypes[i];

                    dataRow[columnName] = Convert.ChangeType(row[i], columnType);
                }

                dataTable.AddRow(dataRow);
            }

            return dataTable;
        }

        public static DataTable ToDataTable(this Table table)
        {
            return table.ToDataTable<string>();
        }

        public static DataTable ToDataTable<TColumn0>(this Table table)
        {
            return table.ToDateTable(typeof(TColumn0));
        }

        public static DataTable ToDataTable<TColumn0, TColumn1>(this Table table)
        {
            return table.ToDateTable(typeof(TColumn0), typeof(TColumn1));
        }

        public static DataTable ToDataTable<TColumn0, TColumn1, TColumn2>(this Table table)
        {
            return table.ToDateTable(typeof(TColumn0), typeof(TColumn1), typeof(TColumn2));
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you a `DataTable` with matching column names, and overloads exist to create `DataRow` objects with strongly typed-ish columns.

For your example, you would use it as:

```
Given Num List
    | num |
    | 1   | 
    | 2   | 
    | 3   |
    | 4   |
    | 5   |
    | 6   |
    | 7   |
    | 8   |
    | 9   |
    | 10  |
```

And the step definition:

```
[Given(@"...")]
public void GivenNumList(Table table)
{
    DataTable dataTable = table.ToDataTable<int>();

    // dataTable.Rows[0]["num"] is an int
}
```

You could keep adding overloads of `ToDataTable` and specify as many generic types as your project needs, and the logic is nice and generic, making it very reusable.

If you had a SpecFlow table with two columns:

```
Given some list
    | age | name    |
    | 2   | Billy   |
    | 85  | Mildred |
```

The step definition would be:

```
public void GivenSomeList(Table table)
{
    DataTable dataTable = table.ToDateTable<int, string>();

    // use it
}
```

Specify the generic types in the order you specify the SpecFlow columns.